# Object initialisation - The relation of the constructor to class type and method access

Tags: java, methods, constructor, initialization, new-operator

I have the following code:

```
package testapp;

class Calculation {

    public Calculation(){}

    public void addition(int x, int y) {   }

    public void Subtraction(int x, int y) {   }
}

class My_Calculation extends Calculation {

    public My_Calculation(){}

    public void multiplication(int x, int y) {   }
}

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int a = 20, b = 10;

        My_Calculation demo = new My_Calculation();
        demo.addition(a, b);
        demo.Subtraction(a, b);
        demo.multiplication(a, b);
        System.out.println(demo.getClass().getName());

        Calculation d = new Calculation();
        d.Subtraction(b, b);
        d.addition(b, b);
        // no multiplication
        System.out.println(d.getClass().getName());

        Calculation d2 = new My_Calculation();
        d2.Subtraction(b, b);
        d2.addition(b, b);
        // no multiplication
        System.out.println(d2.getClass().getName());
    } 
}
```

The output is this:

demo = **testapp.My_Calculation**

d = **testapp.Calculation**

d2 = **testapp.My_Calculation**

The following statement is a declaration that references variable name **d2** to object type **Calculation**:

```
Calculation d2;
```

The following statement is an initialisation that calls My_Calculation constructor.

```
Calculation d2 = new My_Calculation();
```

When I run the following code, the output states that **d2** is of class type **My_Calculation** but gives access to the methods within **Calculation class**.

```
System.out.println(d2.getClass().getName());
```

Output: **testapp.My_Calculation**

Access: **addition; subtraction**

Now, my understanding tells me that if My_Calculation constructor is called I should either have:

**1. access to multiplication ONLY, or**

**2. access to addition, subtraction and multiplication.**

But, I actually get the inverse: **access to addition and subtraction ONLY**. Thus, I see this as counter-intuitive.

Could someone explain to me what is happening here to give me a coherent understanding of why an object of **type: My_Calculation** would have no access to its **own methods** but access to **only the superclasses methods**.

Comment: Put yourself in the shoes of the compiler: you need to compile a method `foo(Calculation c) { ... }`. Would it be safe to accept a call to `c.multiplication()` in this method?

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Method names go camelCase() always, and they should contain a verb, like `multiply()` . And: do not use _ in normal names, they only go into SOME_CONSTANT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
Calculation d2 = new My_Calculation();
```

You create an object of type `My_Calculation`, but you assign it to a variable declared with the supertype! And the compiler isn't smart enough to "see" that `d2` is actually of the child type. Thus the *compiler* prevents you from calling a method defined on that child type. Because to the compiler, `d2` is known to be a `Calculation`!

Note that you can *cast* to tell the compiler "I know better":

```
( (My_Calculation) d2) ).multiplication(...
```

that would work at compile time, and also at runtime!

Your misconception starts here:

```
Calculation d2 = new My_Calculation();
```

What you do on the *right hand side* of the assignment is basically "forgotten" in the next line. Then the compiler **only** knows that you have some `d2` of type `Calculation`!

Finally: yes, in your *specific* example, the compiler could easily determine the *real* type of `d2`. But there are many situations where that isn't easy, or even impossible. Thus the people behind Java decided to ignore such potential "knowledge".

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone explain to me what is happening here to give me a
>   coherent understanding of why an object of type: My_Calculation would
>   have no access to its own methods but access to only the superclasses
>   methods.

Because this is not the object that accesses to the method in the point of view of the compiler, that is the variable that references that.
If you declare :

```
Calculation d2 = new My_Calculation();
```

Or the object reference if you don't declare any variable such as :

```
new My_Calculation().doMethod();
```

The compiler consider `d2` as a `Calculation` and so allows to do what this class offers.
That way of doing is called programming by interface/supertype. It means that you may pass any implementation in the instantiated type and the code will always work.
For example with this change :

```
Calculation d2 = new MyCalculationOtherSubclass();
```

The whole code could compile if `MyCalculationOtherSubclass` is another subclass of `Calculation`.

If you need to work with a specific subtype, declaring the subtype makes sense :

```
My_Calculation d2 = new My_Calculation();
```

or so downcast it :     `((My_Calculation)d2).invokeSubclassMethod();`.
Similarly `String` is a subclass of `CharSequence` but if you want to use `subString()` that is specific to `String`, you need to manipulate a `String` :
So you will declare it :    `String aString = "...";` and not     `CharSequence aString = "...";`.

Answer (score 1):

That is because, at compile time, you only have access to methods from the static type of the object you are dealing with (that is the type of your variable) and to the ones from its superclasses, interfaces and superinterfaces. The `getClass` method is available because it is defined inside the `Object` class, and `Calculation` inherits from it. Hence if you want to call `multiplication` you have to declare your variable as `My_Calculation`.

At runtime however, the method that is invoked is the one from the dynamic type (the one that you assign to the variable). Thus if you override the method `addition` inside `My_Calculation`, that one will be the one invoked at runtime even if the static type is `Calculation`.